# Hide mobile safari address bar

Tags: html

Does anyone know the meta tag I have to use in order to hide safari or any other mobile browser address bar after the page load?

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript to scroll the page down 1px. Doing so will automatically hide the address bar.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function(){window.scrollTo(0, 1);}, 1);
}
```